# Is there any way to zoom out based on the zoom level set by setViewBounds?

Tags: javascript, here-api

Javascript version v3/3.0

When using the setViewBounds to focus on two markers it doesn't set a reasonable margin in the markers. For that reason the content which is on the map overlaps the markers according to the zoom set by setViewBounds

I have tried to use

```
map.setZoom(15.5, true);
```

but it doesn't give a dynamic zoom level as setViewBounds does.

I expect to have a method in the HERE map API that would allow me to set a margin so that the content wouldn't overlap the markers.

https://res.cloudinary.com/dm9mvflp4/image/upload/v1564417172/card-map_emg1fp.png

Comment: Which version of the JavaScript SDK are you using?

Comment: @NicRaboy v3/3.0

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
map.getViewPort().setPadding(...)
```

after initalizing the map. The setting sticks, so if you setViewBounds afterwards it should take the viewport padding into account.

[API Reference: H.Map#getViewPort](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map.html#h-map__getviewport)

[API Reference: H.map.ViewPort#setPadding](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-viewport.html#h-map-viewport__setpadding)